# VS2010 Setup Project- GAC only, without Application Folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gac, setup-deployment

I need to deploy a setup project that only installs an assembly in the GAC - I don't need anything on the start menu, in Program Files, or anywhere else.

The File System dialog for the project won't let me remove the Application Folder or other default entries.

Is this just impossible, or am I missing something?

Also, I'd like the assembly to be registered for both 32- and 64-bit. Is there a convenient way to configure this in the setup project?